# I looking fora solution to use JOIN and GROUP by in this case

Tags: mysql, join, group

I am new in MYSQL and I looking how can a JOIN two tables and bring a result with some conditions:

SERVICE TABLE

| cod | Company | client | cod_prod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9221 | A | 3936 | 10 |
| 9221 | A | 3936 | 55 |
| 9221 | A | 3936 | 3 |
| 9221 | A | 3936 | 18 |
| 9222 | B | 105 | 1 |
| 9222 | B | 105 | 18 |
| 9224 | A | 200 | 6 |
| 9224 | A | 200 | 66 |
| 9224 | A | 200 | 12 |
| 9224 | B | 146 | 18 |
| 9224 | B | 146 | 60 |

LOG TABLE

| cod | Company | Status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9221 | A | entering | 05/11/2022 |
| 9221 | A | redo | 06/11/2022 |
| 9221 | A | working | 07/11/2022 |
| 9222 | B | new | 09/11/2022 |
| 9222 | B | diagnosis | 10/11/2022 |
| 9224 | A | working | 11/11/2022 |
| 9224 | A | done | 12/11/2022 |
| 9224 | B | new | 05/11/2022 |
| 9224 | B | diagnosis | 06/11/2022 |

I saw many examples, but none of them helped me to build these queries
The 'cod' sometimes is equal, but each Company has a unique 'cod'.
I trying to find two summaries for each company with the last date but only when status is 'diagnosis' and 'done'

SUMMARY COMPANY A

| cod | Company | client | Last Status | Last date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9224 | A | 200 | done | 12/11/2022 |

SUMMARY COMPANY B

| cod | Company | client | Last Status | Last date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9222 | B | 105 | diagnosis | 10/11/2022 |
| 9224 | B | 146 | diagnosis | 06/11/2022 |

I'm trying this https://dbfiddle.uk/zKjLkjBx

Comment: Why does 9221/a/diagnosis not appear in your desired outcome -

Comment: P. Salmon, I got a error in log table... second row actually is 'redo' status

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Outcome is impossible given source data.

Comment: And If I concatenate company and cod to use as aggregator?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the schema you provided it is impossible to get the results you are seeking - there is no way to link the client to the log table.

Comment: I know that I have a main aggregated field: Company.
In a second level we have 'cod' field, so, do you agree or do you think that miss something?

Comment: And I know that I need two different queries, one for each Company

Comment: I told you what you were missing